# Не знаю как сделать чтобы бот отправлял файл, aiogram. Нужно отправлять файл через id. Пытался по разному, всегда разные ошибки. мало скила

Tags: файлы, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['oll'])
async def send_oll_file(message: types.Message):
    file_oll_id = "BQACAgIAAxkBAAIDCGMBNC81L5L6EQ9jo5B02Lm2ODuXAAKQHQACxLcISP3Z-4VzpRc8KQQ"
    await bot.send_file(chat_id=message.chat.id, file=file_oll_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['oll'])
async def send_oll_file(message: types.Message):
doc = "BQACAgIAAxkBAAIDCGMBNC81L5L6EQ9jo5B02Lm2ODuXAAKQHQACxLcISP3Z- 
       4VzpRc8KQQ"
    await message.reply_document(doc)
```